# Win32com.client.Dispatch getting wrong when Excel's cell in editable

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I get a request that acquire Excel's cell when mouse click, Im using `win32com.client.Dispatch` to get exist excel object, it looks well until this step but get stuck in next step.
Push my code here

```
xl = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("excel.Application")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("get selection POS:{}".format(xl.Selection.Address))
print("get selection TEXT:{}".format(xl.Selection.Text))
```

My question is that when cell in editable(double click for cell) and this code goes wrong, if you single click, nothing...
push this error here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zqsu3\Desktop\working\recorder-v1.0\hook\EventController.py", line 59, in dispatch
    new_loop.run_until_complete(self._input_event())
  File "c:\users\zqsu3\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\zqsu3\Desktop\working\recorder-v1.0\hook\EventController.py", line 68, in _input_event
    flag, event = self.cond.Special(event, self.key_before)
  File "C:\Users\zqsu3\Desktop\working\recorder-v1.0\utils\cond.py", line 74, in Special
    print(" get selection POS:{}".format(xl.Selection.Address))
  File "C:\Users\zqsu3\Desktop\working\recorder-v1.0\env-3.7.9-32\recorder-3.7.9-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 639, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: excel.Application.Selection
```

So, would someone getting stuck here and slove it? help!!